# Switching between material-tab in AngularDart destroys child elements

Tags: html, angular, iframe, dart, angular-dart

Switching between tabs created with "material-tab" destroys all the child elements of this "tab" in the dom.

You can find below the project files of a simple app to reproduce my problem.
i am using dart 2 sdk and with angular 5.0.0 as dependencies

main.dart:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_web_app/app_component.template.dart' as ng;

void main() {
    runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory);
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my web app</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <script defer src="main.dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

app_component.dart:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: [ coreDirectives, materialDirectives],
  providers: [materialProviders],
)
class AppComponent{}
```

app_component.html:

```
<material-tab-panel>
    <material-tab label="Music">
        <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
                src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/JvqXj2cAaY4?autoplay=1'
                frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </material-tab>
    <material-tab label="Favorites">
        <h2>My favorite musics</h2>
    </material-tab>
</material-tab-panel>
```

Nothing special here compared to the default generated files, i just have a custom app_component.html, only need to add materialDirectives and materialProviders to our AppComponent as you see.

you see a single page with 2 tabs:

- "Music" tab contains an embedded youtube iframe
- "Favorites" tab contains just some html (ideally a list of youtube
  video i want to play)

So when i click on Music tab the iframe start playing the music, but when i click on Favorites tab the iframe doesn't play anymore the music.
When inspecting the dom with chrome dev tools, i see that the content of a tab is "wiped" (not sure if it is the right word) from the dom.
And only when when the tab is clicked again the content of the tab is added again to the dom.
This is really what we need in general, but for this particular case i really would like to have the iframe still playing music, while users browse their favorites music list.

Do you have any ideas or sample codes for :

- keep content of dom attached to dom even when we change tab (this way
  the iframe should be still running even when we switch tab)
- or just a way to keep the youtube iframe playing (maybe in a global
  way ? but that seems dirty)

As i am new in dart and angular maybe i missed a design pattern/strategy or features that i didn't use.

If you follow this jsfiddle link you can find what i really want to do but this is with raw js/html: https://jsfiddle.net/gsfkL6xL/353/

Answer (score 2):

`material-tab` uses NgIf under the hood which removes the DOM. As a default we have found this to be what you normally want. It is more performant to remove those nodes, and not have angular change detect them, or have the browser need to draw them.

You can see the implementation here: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/8083c3e4e98b7cb6d20c10c791500dfcc5cb74ee/lib/material_tab/material_tab.dart#L56

That said material-tab-panel was made so that you could make your own implementation of material-tab such as hidden-tab that will make the div linked above hidden/shown instead of using an NgIf.

An easy way to do this would be to extend the tab like so:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'hidden-tab',
  providers: const [
    const Provider(Tab, useExisting: HiddenTabComponent),
    const Provider(DeferredContentAware, useExisting: HiddenTabComponent)
  ],
  template: '''
        <div class="tab-content" [hidden]="!active">
          <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>''',
  styleUrls: const ['package:angular_components/material_tab/material_tab.scss.css'],
)
class HiddenTabComponent extends MaterialTabComponent {}
```

Sorry for any errors whiteboarded the code.

Comment: OK so the div you linked should be <div class="tab-content [hidden]="!active">.
Should i extend the MaterialTabComponent to perform this or rewrite from scratch a MaterialHiddenTabComponent ? Sorry to ask but some code would be really great!

Comment: Great! I will edit your answer and add what is missing in your code snippet (like call of parent constructor) and add the modification in the others file if needed, and then i will validate your answer! This way future viewers will get a full working example. Thanks a lot!